# Attach JavaScript array to mail

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml, email

I have a simple calculator on my contact page which creates two arrays in my JavaScript.  What I want is, when the user fills the form and sends his mail, the two arrays attach aswell. Idk, maybe via jSon file, or XML or anything, doesn't matter. I just want the receiver to have that data.

Comment: The receiver will never be able to do anything with the file in the email. It would have to be CSV or other attachment that could run in a separate program after download. Emails will not execute JS

Comment: I know that, I don't mind the way as long as the receiver gets to read the data, be it pdf, json file from the web (I dont want this btw, cause the file will be stored in the web), or simply text added at the end of the mail

Answer (score 0):

The email is not sent with Javascript. You can send the information to the server in a similar way you send it the "to" address and the "message", but you need to work how to send array info in the email on the server.

The way you send the array to the server depends on the language you use on the server.

If it is php:

1) You can encode the array to a Json string and set the string as the value of an input form.

2) Or use the name property of the input tag like `myarray[n]` where n is the position of the value in the array.

```
<input name="myarray[0]" value = "first value"/>
<input name="myarray[1]" value = "second value"/>
<input name="myarray[2]" value = "third value"/>
```

And then pick it up on the php side with `$_POST['myarray']`;

Comment: Great. I'll try that, but one more question.
I'd like to add more values instead of just one, "first value", "second value".
And then also one VAR (which stores the total sum of all)

Comment: or maybe in one value input, include a variable? that would be even easier.
let's say:   value = "first value"+array[5]/> 
Can this be done?

Comment: If you go that way, use JSON.stringify(array), and you can decode it on the php side (Option 1 of my answer)

Comment: This is working for me, but I just need to make it look a bit cleaner (When I alert the JSON, it looks messy,  without line breaks).

I  need to know how to attach this JSON to a mail alongside the other contact infos (name, phone, msg..), but in plain text, no need for more complications.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to do. JSON is just a format to serialize an object. Once you receive the json string on the server you can instantiate an object or as an Associative array. And from there you can include the data in the emial in whatever format you want.